# maven site for multi module

Tags: maven-2, maven-site-plugin

I have a maven project with lots of sub-modules, and I use parent pom to control the plugins the directory like below

```
-pom.xml (parent pom)
 +- submodule1
 +- submodule2
 +- src\site\site.xml
```

therefore `src\site\site.xml` contains the customized menu like below

```
<project>
  ....
  <body>
   <menu name="Overview">
    <item name="Introduction" href="introduction.html"/>
   </menu>
   <menu name="Development">
      <item name="Getting started" href="designenv.html"/>
      <item name="FAQ" href="designfaq.html" />
      <item name="Javadoc" href="apidocs/index.html" />
   </menu>
   <menu ref="modules"/>
   <menu ref="reports"/>
 </body>
</project>
```

After I run `mvn site:stage` in root (suggested from [maven site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html)), the parent webpage is fine, while the `<sub-modules>\index.html` doesn't contain any menu (no project info & project report)

Also I notice if I run `mvn site` under sub-modules, the index.html doesn't contain any menu in left, while the individual html exist in directory like pmd.html, license.html

- Do I need to add `src\site\site.xml` in each sub-module or other better way ?
- or Did I do something stupid in `pom.xml` somewhere ?

Any hints ?

[update] also like for banner image, if I set in parent like this

```
<bannerLeft>
  <name>edcp</name>
  <src>images/mylogo.png</src>
</bannerLeft>
```

The site for sub-module with points to wrong direction, in html, looks like `..\..\<submodule>`, not `..\images\mylogo.png`

Comment: If I add simple site.xml under each submodule, it works fine now

Comment: You could answer your own question and select it as correct. This way it would be visible from the overview pages that the question has a solution.

Comment: it is a not a good solution as I expected, and I still want to have people to give me better answer, and this system recommend not to answer my own question.

Comment: Ok, that's fine so far (if you still want to get answers) - but then you first comment is misleading ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to avoid copying the site.xml to each submodule manually, then using the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) could be a workaround: Add this to your parent pom:

```
[...]
<properties>
    <site.basedir>${project.basedir}</site.basedir>
</properties>
[...]
<build> 
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-sitedescriptor</id>
        <!-- fetch site.xml before creating site documentation -->
        <phase>pre-site</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/site/</outputDirectory>
          <resources>          
            <resource>                  
              <directory>${site.basedir}/src/site/</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/site.xml</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </resources>              
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```

and this to each of your submodule poms:

```
<properties>
    <site.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</site.basedir>
</properties>
```

Then the site descriptor will be copied from the parent project to each submodule (overwriting existing descriptors) before the site documentation is created. Please note that the src/site directory must exist in each submodule to make this work. Not a perfect solution, but maybe better than a complete manual one.

Comment: Possibly superseded by the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848715/multi-module-pom-creating-a-site-that-works

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to inherit menus from the parent `site.xml` by using the `inherit` attribute.

E.g,

```
<project>
  ....
  <body>
   <menu name="Overview" inherit="top">
    <item name="Introduction" href="introduction.html"/>
   </menu>
   <menu name="Development" inherit="top">
      <item name="Getting started" href="designenv.html"/>
      <item name="FAQ" href="designfaq.html" />
      <item name="Javadoc" href="apidocs/index.html" />
   </menu>
   <menu ref="modules"/>
   <menu ref="reports"/>
 </body>
</project>
```

Now both the `Overview` and `Development` menus will be inherited by all sub-projects.

See the Maven documentation for multi-module sites for more details, 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/multimodule.html#Inheritance

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this when trying to generate a multi module maven site and just wanted to share a solution I came up with.

In your parent pom add

```
<siteDirectory>${session.executionRootDirectory}/src/site</siteDirectory>
```

to the maven site plugin configuration.

That should tell all the child poms to get their site.xml from the parent directory.

Comment: However, this will completely ignore whatever is specific for the child modules. First I also thought this would be the solution, but it does something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a small Python script that creates all the `site.xml` files from a template. [Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/digulla/5133131).