# Multi-module example of using mvn site-deploy with github pages

Tags: maven, github, github-pages

I am looking for an example `pom.xm`l and `settings.xml` setup that shows how to deploy to github pages that uses the standard maven site deployment target `site-deploy` and is also multi-module.

Specifically I am looking for one that works in both Windows as well as UNIX.

Searching around, I haven't found an example that works.  Some of the ones I have looked at are:

- wagon-gitsite http://khuxtable.github.io/wagon-gitsite/usage.html
- @kohsuke github-api https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/blob/master/pom.xml
- Maven SCM Publish plugin https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSCMPUB-4 (though this does not count since it does not work with site-deploy, it has it's own target `scm-publish:publish-scm`)

None of them work as well as the wagon-ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I released a plugin that will handle the multi-module project scenario with github pages.  It is a matter of setting the following dependency on `maven-site-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.trajano.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-git</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The following is the multi-module example https://github.com/trajano/app/tree/wagon-git-example which can be seen at http://site.trajano.net/app/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at GitHub's [site-maven-plugin](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins#site-plugin)?  It seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: I have, but there's no example of it that shows how it works with multiproject.  I couldn't get it working with that either.

Comment: Yeah, [issue #22](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/22) implies that either it doesn't work or it isn't obvious...

Answer (score 0):

see the example

- https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.multimodule

and detailed analysis

- http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Multi-Module_Maven_with_github_pages

suggesting to simply use maven-site-plugin and a bash-script function.