# Getting error deploying mvn site:deploy

Tags: java, maven, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have configured my project with cobertura and I'm new to this.

I want to deploy mvn site. Since it is a multi module project I first did

```
mvn site:site 
mvn site:stage
```

Till here I was able to get the site with all the links properly working.
But when I try to do **mvn site:deploy** I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.5.1:deploy (default-cli) on project Myproject: Error uploading site: Error copying directory structure: Could not create destination directory '/./css'. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.5.1:deploy (default-cli) on project Myproject: Error uploading site
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error uploading site
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push(AbstractDeployMojo.java:466)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:332)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo(AbstractDeployMojo.java:293)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.execute(AbstractDeployMojo.java:172)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error copying directory structure
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.putDirectory(FileWagon.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push(AbstractDeployMojo.java:449)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create destination directory '/./css'.
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyDirectoryStructure(FileUtils.java:2173)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyDirectoryStructure(FileUtils.java:2092)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.file.FileWagon.putDirectory(FileWagon.java:194)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is my distribution management in pom

```
</distributionManagement>
    .....
    <site>
        <id>localhost</id>
        <url>file://localhost:8080/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

Please help.

Comment: maven wont be able to find path like this file://localhost:8080/
you need to give path such as file://${project.build.directory}/sitedir

Comment: @kuhajeyan Can you please provide an example. I want to deploy this on a remote server and access it through an url.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19028760/410677

Comment: I have changed url to file://${project.build.directory}/Report and it is running without any error. How can I access this. I don't find an Report directory in my Tomcat

Comment: I use tomcat for deployment. I want to access it via an url. Getting really confused. please help